# What are the visual differences between Boba and Jango Fett's armor?

Tags: star-wars

Or, how exactly can you tell them apart?  Is the armor completely the same except for the color, or are there some other differences?

Comment: Also, does he wear his Dad's actual helmet? The one that he picked up, with his Dad's head in it.

Comment: @StuperUser I always assumed that he either wore the same helmet, or had one made exactly the same as his fathers (since he had it in his possession).

Comment: In Star Wars: The Clone Wars Season 2 Episode 21 it shows Jango Fett's helmet destroyed and split into two and it goes down with the Jedi cruiser when it blows up.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a nice side-by-side that illustrates all of the differences.

[image: Boba and Jango Fett]

Comment: Nice picture!  So there's the color, and boba fett's armor is more scratched up and he wears a little cape thingy...and the legs are different...and once gun instead of two?  Is that all of it?

Comment: Boba has replaced parts, has changed his color scheme slightly, and has had his armor damaged significantly more than his father did.  He also (I believe) has built in more weaponry.

Comment: He has dart weaponry with his legs.  He may also have deduced that mobility was a priority given the wide-spectrum of environments he dealt with while hunting Jedi.  Also- Lucas liked shiny with the prequels.

Comment: It's less visible in this photo, but Boba also has Wookiee scalps hanging from his right shoulder.

Comment: Both use Batman's utility belt...

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas But it was "A long time ago" ... so Bruce is using theirs.....

Comment: This picture-only answer is completely [inaccessible](http://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/accessibility). *Some* effort should have been made or edited in to list at least the major differences in text.

Comment: @CreationEdge Please feel free to. This is an extremely old question for this site, from when it was first being decided what was and wasn't acceptable.

Comment: @DampeS8N Yeah, I noticed that *after* I posted the comment. The question was at the top of the question list, I didn't pay attention to the fact that it wasn't the "newest" list.

Answer (score 2):

Jango (on the right) has fresher, cleaner, shinier armor due to it not being as old. Boba (on the left) has armor that is more weathered and scratched up, you can see that it's really quite aged. So just remember Boba is the clone of Jango and was raised as his son, meaning he's younger so he would naturally get he older armor that Jango once owned.

Comment: Just because he's younger (and his "son") doesn't automatically imply he would wear the same armor that Jango did. There's enough visual differences in the armor pieces alone to suggest that it's some other set of Mandalorian armor that his father either had in his possession or Boba acquired himself.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that Jango Fett's back story is that death watch basically kicked his faction of Mandalorians off the planet of those who weren't wiped out. After the rise of the empire I imagine Boba took steps in helping change his position.

His father (Jango) was part of a "neo-crusader" movement which opposed death watch, If they were wiped out by the rise of the rebellion that could explain why Boba wears the insignia of his home planet.

I'm not sure on all the details but in the expanded universe Boba becomes the new Mandalore (warrior leader of Mandalorians everywhere) and leads a new generation of Mandalorian warriors to mostly help the new republic, not that he hasn't tried to hurt them also.

In some other figures he has a single pistol on his back leg the type his father used. Perhaps he kept them or those pistols were the "no disintegration" demanded by Vader, Perhaps he had not changed weapons between then and his stay at Jabba's palace, or more likely he didn't need as powerful weapons while in a stronghold of a Hutt.

Answer (score 1):

Jango Fett has front thigh armor and Boba doesn't. Also Boba has more advanced gauntlets that have a better laser volley and an ELECTRIC, steel cord plus everything his father had in the gauntlets. Boba also has built in knee darts, and the color is obviously different. Jango's armor is more shiny and less used and Boba's armor is more withered and dented. Also their helmets are much different. Jango's is more slim at the top while Boba's is large at the top. Boba's visor is also thin and Jango's is thicker. The antennas are also different. Also Boba wears another layer under his armor (sometimes). Its like a flak vest that's made of Krayt Dragon skin and can withstand a lot of damage. That's all, I think.

Comment: Sources? And how would you be able to detect some of these differences visually (e.g. Boba's under armor)?

Answer (score 0):

Collectible helmet made from the original mold.

[image]

Jango's helmet is also noticeably longer, though I suspect he has multiple sets (Boba's green colour may even be a jungle-specific set of Jango's)